# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when trying to run VSDBCMD.exe

Tags: database-project, vsdbcmd

We are trying to deploy a database project using tfs deployer and "vsdbcmd.exe" (VS 2010 version).

Both are on a windows server 2008 r2 (64 bit).

When our deployment script runs and we call the `VSDBCMD.exe`, we get the following error:
`An unexpected failure occurred: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Note: SQL Server is not installed on this server, the script calls to a different server which has the databases we want to execute the database schemas against. Visual studio is also not installed on this server so I executed `reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0` as I found a missing registry key could be causing the issue. However, the problem still occurs

The dll's copied to the server are:

```
Extensions (folder)
DatabaseSchemaProviders.Extensions.xml

Microsoft.Data.Schema.dll

Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom.dll

Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom.Sql.dll

Microsoft.Data.Schema.Sql.dll

Microsoft.Data.Schema.Utilities.dll

Sqlceer35en.dll

Sqlceme35.dll

Sqlceqp35.dll

Sqlcese35.dll

sqlceca35.dll

sqlcecompact35.dll

sqlceoledb35.dll

System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll

vsdbcmd.exe

vsdbcmd.exe.config
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this would be great

Thanks,

Ryan

Comment: Have you looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193258%28v=VS.100%29.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bahill/archive/2009/02/21/deploying-your-database-project-without-vstsdb-installed.aspx ? They may have something you're missing. We moved on to SSDT and just installed those bits on the server to work around the missing bits issues - it's a somewhat smaller install.